# Chantry management

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

A group of mages push technocracy out of Shelbyville and create their own Chantry there near a node. What would be the rules of managing the Chantry, or does it simply rely on dots in Chantry background instead of having to be managed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Mage: The Ascension* supplement ***Book of Chantries*** (1995) may be your friend; it's available [in PDF](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/m/product/40) or used, for example, [on *Amazon*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565040848).

While you can handle a chantry however you want (as just a location or an entire setting), *Book of Chantries* provides a lot more insight into how some famous ones worked. Further, the book offers rules for creating and maintaining a chantry if players want to get into the weeds of it.